# Properly unmarshal uncertain JSON with proper return type

Tags: json, go

I am working with a JSON API to pull forex quotes.

I am unmarshaling to a `struct` like so:

```
type Quote struct {
    Symbol string
    Bid float32
    Ask float32
    Price float32
    Timestamp int
}
```

Using a `function` like so:

```
func GetQuotes(symbols []string, api_key string) []Quote {
    result := fetch("quotes?pairs=" + strings.Join(symbols, ","), api_key)

    quotes := []Quote{}

    e := json.Unmarshal(result, &quotes)

    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }

    return quotes
}
```

My issue is: If I get back an error such as "The data you've requested is not available", **how do I properly return the correct type from `GetQuotes`?**

If I unmarshal using `json.RawMessage` I can use a switch to chose the proper struct, such as `Quote` or `ErrorMessage`, however, then I cannot set a proper return type from `GetQuotes`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to follow the Go way, and return both error and Quotes, here is an example:

```
func GetQuotes(symbols []string, api_key string) ([]Quote, error) {        
    quotes := []Quote{}
    // A better would be if the fetch 
    // fuction also returns both 
    // result and error
    result := fetch("quotes?pairs=" + strings.Join(symbols, ","), api_key)

    e := json.Unmarshal(result, &quotes)

    if e != nil {
        return quotes, e
    }

    return quotes, nil
}
```

Now you can check if request or marshaling returns an error.

```
quotes, err := GetQuotes(symbols, apiKey)
if err != nil {
  // handle errors here
}
```

You can also return the `ErrorMessage` type your custom struct instead of `error`.

<sub>[Error handling and Go](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)</sub>

In order to returns different types, you must use an interface in the return statement, here is an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/sLXlt2EXm4i):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {}

type Bar struct {}

func Baz(w string) interface{} {
  if w == "Foo" {
    return Foo{}
  }
  return Bar{}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%T", Baz("Bar"))
}
=> main.Bar
```

The `Baz` function able to returns both `Foo` and `Bar` structs.